# How to properly import csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I have a csv data which I am trying to import to mysql locally through

```
load data local infile '/mnt/c/Users/justi/Desktop/enml/file.csv' 
into table dict 
fields terminated by '\t' 
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I have following result.

```
Query OK, 216616 rows affected, 1082 warnings (6.68 sec)
Records: 216616  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 1082
```

Some of data imported, but some aren't. Here is the information about csv file.

> The dataset is provided as a non-normalized CSV dump of tab separated
>   values. There are four columns, each separated by a single tab — ID,
>   English word, Part of speech, and definition.

Comment: I think you missed to add " lines terminated by ".. then the query will look like this  " load data local infile  '/mnt/c/Users/justi/Desktop/olam-enml/file.csv' into table dict fields terminated by '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES; "

Comment: Assuming your data have no problems, then typically `LOAD DATA` is an all or nothing thing.  So, I suggest that your input file has problems with it.

Comment: @jithingiri The default line ending is `\n`, so your suggestion should not change anything.  But, maybe the line ending is something else.

Comment: If `fields terminated by '\t'` then its not a CSV file! CSV == _Comma Seperated Values_

Comment: One thing I missed, I created 4 column and set id to auto increment, That may be the problem, this data has its own id. how to correct it

Comment: Fixed by remove auto increment.